# Call PHP function with less parameters then expected by function

Tags: php, function

I have the following PHP function which is working very well:

```
<?php
function my_test_function($par1, $par2, $par3) {
    $string = $par1.$par2.$par3;
    return $string;
}

echo my_test_function('Hello', 'how are', 'you');
?>
```

But if I call the function like this:

```
echo my_test_function('Hello', 'how are');
```

I'll get an error message, because the function needs three parameters and I only send two parameters:

```
[29-Jan-2023 10:29:45 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function my_test_function(), 2 passed in /home/user/public_html/test_file.php on line 7 and exactly 3 expected in /home/user/public_html/test_file.php:2
Stack trace:
#0 /home/user/public_html/test_file.php(7): my_test_function('Hello', 'how are')
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/user/public_html/test_file.php on line 2
```

Is there a way to send less parameters than expected by the function? I'd like to call the function with two parameters, although tree are expected.

I know, I could just make the third parameter empty but this isn't my goal.

Comment: We cannot really answer to such a question. Because it is unclear what you are actually trying to achieve. Without goal there is no way to sketch a route. If a function expects three parameters then there is a reason for that. It's logic is implemented based on those three parameters. Which means that you are trying to twist that logic to something it has not been meant to do. The only situation where that might make sense is if you know how that logic will react without that third parameter. But then you could simply use a default value. To which you just say that you don't want to do that.

Comment: Call the function with a object, in  the function, check witch parts of the object are set to use.

Comment: What's your goal? What does "make empty" mean?

Comment: @shingo I mean that: `echo my_test_function('Hello', 'how are', '');`

Comment: @shingo Yes, answer of Luuk is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a parameter optional like this:

```php
<?php
function my_test_function($par1, $par2, $par3 = "all of you") {
    $string = $par1.$par2.$par3;
    return $string;
}

echo my_test_function('Hello', 'how are', 'you');

echo my_test_function('Hello', 'how are');
?>
```

This will return:

```
Hellohow areyou
Hellohow areall of you
```

Comment: That's is, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use a function without knowing the number of arguments there is a technique that will please you, it is to use spread operators.
[here is the link of the php doc](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/spread_operator_for_array)
you can do write function like that :

```php
function concatMyXStrings(...$strings){
    $out = '';
    foreach($strings as $string){
        $out .= $string;
    }
    return $out;
}
```

you pass 1 or x arguments, almost without worrying about what you will send or receive...

```php
concatMyXStrings('I', ' ', 'love ', ' stack', ' ', ' !');
// or
concatMyXStrings('pink ', 'floyd');
```

you loop on it like an array to forge your string by concatenating at each iteration and normally, with that, you're saved!

edit : you can also use implode pour concatenation like this for avoid using a foreach loop

```php
// ...
return implode('',$strings);
// ...
```